# Как добавить css-класс коллекции элементов через js?

Tags: javascript, css, классы, циклы

Есть несколько блоков с классом `.crs-card-big` (пример ниже).

Я объявил переменную `const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.crs-card-big');`.

Как с помощью js добавить всем карточкам (`const cards`) класс `.crs-card-big_theme-dark`?

```html
<div class="crs-card-big crs-card__default" id="theme__1">
         <div class="crs-card__content"></div>
         <div class="crs-card__img">
            <img src="img/img_magnifer.png" alt="Лупа" class="img-fluid animation__fly">
         </div>
         <img src="img/shape_1.svg" alt="Фигура" class="img-fluid shape">
      </div>
```

Comment: классическим перебором

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на JavaScript

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.crs-card-big');
for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++ ){
    cards[i].classList.add('crs-card-big_theme-dark');

}
```

Вариант на JQuery

```
var cards = $('.crs-card-big')
cards.addClass('test');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вариант с циклом подошел)